# How do disable download access from sub folder

Tags: .htaccess

I want to disable all download access from this folder.

`public_html\a\b\test.pdf`

I've already added `Deny from all` code `public_html\a\b\.htaccess` file. But I think in my server `AllowIOverwrite` is not enabled with sub folders.

Is there any optional way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure...

In public_html\a\b.htaccess :

`Options All -Indexes`

check here : https://www.countryipblocks.net/prevent-directory-indexing-with-htaccess

Else make index.html in folder public_html\a\b\ ...

Comment: Thanks. I'm not talking about file browsing, I want to disable FILE DOWNLOADING.